# Porting bit operations from Python to C#

Tags: python, c#, raspberry-pi, spi, adafruit-circuitpython

I am working on a C# port of the [Adafruit_CircuitPython_RFM69](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_RFM69/blob/main/adafruit_rfm69.py) Python library which is an SPI radio module library that I'm using with a Raspberry Pi.

I have most of the python properties ported over and tested/working successfully, except for being able to get/set the [frequency_mhz](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_RFM69/blob/864012e8644f7dc5dfba32a43af52a1f48969c7a/adafruit_rfm69.py#L585) & [frequency_deviation](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_RFM69/blob/864012e8644f7dc5dfba32a43af52a1f48969c7a/adafruit_rfm69.py#L725) Python properties.

I'm unable to receive any radio packets with my C# port, but the Python version works flawlessly, and I suspect the two properties in question is the reason why.

Frequency:

```
// works? - not perfectly accurate
rfm.Frequency = 433;
Console.WriteLine("Frequency: {0}", rfm.Frequency); // after setting 'rfm.Frequency = 433' the get method reports '432'

private int GetFrequency()
{
    // FRF register is computed from the frequency following the datasheet.
    // See section 6.2 and FRF register description.
    // Read bytes of FRF register and assemble into a 24-bit unsigned value.
    byte msb = ReadByte(_REG_FRF_MSB);
    byte mid = ReadByte(_REG_FRF_MID);
    byte lsb = ReadByte(_REG_FRF_LSB);
    int frf = ((msb << 16) | (mid << 8) | lsb) & 0xFFFFFF;
    int frequency = (frf * _FSTEP) / 1000000;
    return frequency;
}

private void SetFrequency(int freq)
{
    if (freq < 290 || freq > 1020)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(freq), freq, "frequency must be between range(290, 1020)");

    // Calculate FRF register 24-bit value using section 6.2 of the datasheet.
    int frf = ((freq * 1000000) / _FSTEP) & 0xFFFFFF;

    // Extract byte values and update registers.
    byte msb = (byte)(frf >> 16);
    byte mid = (byte)((frf >> 8) & 0xFF);
    byte lsb = (byte)(frf & 0xFF);

    WriteByte(_REG_FRF_MSB, msb);
    WriteByte(_REG_FRF_MID, mid);
    WriteByte(_REG_FRF_LSB, lsb);
}
```

FrequencyDeviation:

```
// works? - not perfectly accurate
rfm.FrequencyDeviation = 250000;
Console.WriteLine("FrequencyDeviation: {0}", rfm.FrequencyDeviation); // after setting 'rfm.FrequencyDeviation = 250000' the get method reports '249978'

private int GetFrequencyDeviation()
{
    byte msb = ReadByte(_REG_FDEV_MSB);
    byte lsb = ReadByte(_REG_FDEV_LSB);
    return _FSTEP * ((msb << 8) | lsb);
}

private void SetFrequencyDeviation(int value)
{
    if (value < 0 || value > _FSTEP * 16383) // fdev is a 14-bit unsigned value
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(value), value, $"frequency deviation must be between range(0, {_FSTEP * 16383})");

    // Round up to the next closest integer value with addition of 0.5.

    int fdev = (int)((value / _FSTEP) + 0.5) & 0x3FFF;
    WriteByte(_REG_FDEV_MSB, (byte)(fdev >> 8));
    WriteByte(_REG_FDEV_LSB, (byte)(fdev & 0xFF));
}
```

Any help/pointers is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

I did some testing for getting/setting the two properties in Python and they both return the exact values that were set, I tried many different casts and rounding methods in my C# port to no avail.

I'm expecting to get the same input/output as Python, and I'm unsure why I'm not.

I can't figure out why I can't do the exact same bit operations in C# that are done in the Adafruit Python code. I know it must have something to do with the C# type differences but I'm unsure how to combine/cast the Python types to C# properly.

[Here is the full C# code](https://gist.github.com/tottaka/366ea6801ec6ec51859a302ef0782e1f)

[Here is the RFM69 datasheet](https://www.digikey.com/htmldatasheets/production/1921186/0/0/1/rfm69hcw.html) just in case.

Comment: Where is `_FSETP` defined, what type is it and what value does it have? But apart from that: I would expect inaccuracies to be rooted in the _floating point operations_. Your bit-ops look fine to me. I'd recommend to factor out the conversion methods (to and from 14 bit unsigned) and write unit tests for them. Then you'll see which of your expectations are met and which are not. And based on that you can go try and fix.

Comment: @Fildor **_FSETP** is on line 334 in the github gist I posted of the full C# code

`// The crystal oscillator frequency and frequency synthesizer step size.
// See the datasheet for details of this calculation.
const int _FXOSC = 32000000;
const int _FSTEP = _FXOSC / 524288;`

Comment: @Fildor Could you point me in the right direction to understand how I can factor out the conversion methods? I'm reading individual bytes from an SPI bus that I need to combine into a single value so I'm not sure how I would go about that

Comment: You basically said it in your own words: You read three values _and then_ you need to convert these values. So you can make a function with such a signature: `int To24BitUnsigned(byte msb, byte mid, byte lsb);` which is completely independent of anything (except that _FSETP constant) and can be tested. Same goes for the other way, where you'd have to decide how you want to return 3 values, of course. You could do a `bool Try24BitUnsignedToBytes( int value, out byte msb, out byte mid, out byte lsb);` or `byte[] ToBytes(int unsignedTwentyfour)` or ...

Comment: Maybe you can build on top of this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/SEhI9p. It fixes that one value of 433, but I am unsure if it is correct for the entire value set. And it's only for the 24 bit value. You'll have to do smth similar for the 14 bit one.

Comment: This seems stable across the valid input: https://dotnetfiddle.net/p7NsFN

Comment: @Fildor This definitely works, thank you very much! Now I just have to keep tinkering with the 14-bit version. Should I use `short` for the 14-bit version instead of `int`?

Comment: Got it! Turns out the root of my issue was most likely due to `_FSTEP` being floored by the `int` cast, in the Python version it's actually `61.03515625` which combined with your rounding methods made everything work as expected.

Thank you again!